# PopupWindow cannot display Unity3D views in Android, but Dialog does?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, dialog, android-popupwindow

Here is some brief codes of my project, in which I'd like to display a Unity3D model to do something.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888); 
    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
    ...
    mTestImageButton = ***;
    mTestImageButton.setOnClickListener(mTestImageButtonClickListener);
}
    private ImageButton mTestImageButton;
    private View.OnClickListener mTestImageButtonClickListener = new 
    View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          showUnity3D_dialog(v);
          //showUnity3D_popupwindow(v);
        }
    };
    private void showUnity3D_dialog(View v) {
      Dialog dialog = new Dialog(v.getContext(), R.style.move_dialog);
      dialog.setContentView(mUnityPlayer);
      Window window = dialog.getWindow();
      window.setWindowAnimations(R.style.move_dialog);
      WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
      window.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.BOTTOM);
      lp.width = 1179; 
      lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
      window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
      window.setAttributes(lp);
      dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    }
                });
      dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
      dialog.show();
      mUnityPlayer.resume();
    }
    private void showUnity3D_popupwindow(View v) {
      PopupWindow pop = new PopupWindow(mUnityPlayer, 1000, 800);
      pop.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable()); 
      pop.setFocusable(true);
      pop.setOutsideTouchable(false);
      pop.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss() {

                    }
                });
      pop.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
      mUnityPlayer.resume();
    }
}
```

As codes above, I tried to display a Unity3D-model in a PopupWindow, but the result makes me a bit confused, since there is nothing on screen when I called showUnity3D_popupwindow(v).

But when I called showUnity3D_dialog(v), the model by Unity3D shows.

I really can't understand what caused such scenario, and how can I display my model in a PopupWindow in android? Or, is it an impossible task?

I have my project under Android 4.3 & Unity 5.4.0.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are currently using the [`PopupWindow(View contentView, int width, int height)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#PopupWindow(android.view.View,%20int,%20int)) overload function. I've seen instances where functions that take `View`, `Context` or `Activity` does not work in Unity and you have to try other overloads.

You've tried the one takes `View`, now try the [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#PopupWindow(android.content.Context)) overload:

[`PopupWindow(Context context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#PopupWindow(android.content.Context))

then set the width and height later on with the [`setWidth`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setWidth(int)) and [`setHeight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setHeight(int)) function. You can get the current Context with `UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getApplicationContext()`.

```
private void showUnity3D_popupwindow(View v) 
{
    Context mContext = UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getApplicationContext();
    PopupWindow pop = new PopupWindow(mContext);
    pop.setWidth(1000);
    pop.setHeight(800);

    pop.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    pop.setFocusable(true);
    pop.setOutsideTouchable(false);
    pop.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss() {

    }
    });
    pop.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    mUnityPlayer.resume();
}
```